# Angular ng-smart-table delete confirm modal dose not work

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to use ng-smart-table to shows delete confirm modal when user try to delete row, but the modal does not appear.

I added delete related settings following documents and other examples but still modal does not show.

```html
 <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data" (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)">
    </ng2-smart-table>
```

```
settings = {
    mode: 'external',
    pager: {perPage: 10},
    hideSubHeader: true,
    sort: false,
    actions: {
      position: 'right',
      edit: false,
      delete: true,
      add: false,
    },
    delete: {confirmDelete: true},
    columns: {
      id: {title: 'ID'},
    },
}

onDeleteConfirm($event: any) {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      $event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      $event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }
```

Nothing shows on Chrome Console log.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mode: 'external'` from the settings.
Please refer the demo for better understanding. DEMO https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the ng2-smart-table [documentation](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation):

> Triggered only if table confirmDelete = true and mode = inline.

So please change the mode in settings to **inline** instead of **external**.